# Performing LOOK UP in R to create a new data frame

Tags: r, sas

I have 2 data frames df1 and df2 as below

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:7), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary","Thangu","Xman"),
  dept = c(-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4), 
 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  d1 = c (1:144), 
  d2 = c(3:146),
  d3 = c(5:148),
  d4 =c(7:150),
  d5 =c(9:152),
  d6 =c(11:154),
  d7 =c(13:156),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I want to create a  new data frame with 144 new columns for each employee based on the dept column in df1. For eg Rick belongs to dept -2, so for Rick d1 should be fetched from df2. Likewise, Dan belongs to dept -1, so for Dan d2 has to be fetched.

An equivalent SAS code would be

```
case    when df1.dept= -2 then df2.d1
                        when df1.dept = -1 then df2.d2
                        when df1.dept = 0 then df2.d3
                        when df1.dept = 1 then df2.d4 
else .
                        end) as df3 
)
```

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Why does a dept of -2 in df1 mean selecting column d1 from df2?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what the link between the department and df2$d1? How does department -2 equate d1 in the second dataframe?

Comment: Don;t quite follow your logic but it seems like you probably want to do a merge of some kind.

Comment: @user438383  Yes I want to do a merge, I have attached a SAS code in the question with the logic. I am new to R so trying to get my head around it

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a matching to the actual column names, I've added it to df1 (not the same order as yours, just as an example)

```
df1$deptName=c("d3","d1","d6","d5","d4","d6","d1")
```

then you can do

```
cbind(
  df1,
  t(df2[,df1$deptName])
)

     emp_id emp_name dept deptName  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
d3        1     Rick   -2       d3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
d1        2      Dan   -1       d1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
d6        3 Michelle    0       d6 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
d5        4     Ryan    1       d5  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
d4        5     Gary    2       d4  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
d6.1      6   Thangu    3       d6 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 ...
```